Three Phase DCX LLC secondary side control
I want to design a Three Phase DCX LLC with an input of 400V and an output of 48V. The architecture is shown in the figure below. I have a few questions I’d like to ask everyone:

1 If the secondary side uses a full bridge configuration with synchronous rectification switches, how should the timing of the switches be controlled?
2 Is there a relationship between the timing of the synchronous rectification switches on the primary and secondary sides?
3 Regarding the control methods for the Three Phase DCX LLC, are there any recommended papers for reference?
This figure is come from below link
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10509265

You need a citation for your image more than likely. Have you constructed a simulation of your circuit using conventional bridge rectification diodes in order to understand things better. How have you estimated the peak flux density in the core?

@Andyaka Yes, I try to use simulation tool to understand how it work, but for the secondary side, I use diode not the  synchronous rectification switches
